# Find value of 100 latest values in array

Tags: javascript

I've got an array that is constantly updating with analogue readings from an Arduino pin.

I'd like to create a function that takes the latest 100 values in the array, and returns an average of them (the array has a max length of 100,000 at which it starts 'shifting' and 'pushing' to make space for new values).

I created this function, but it returns 'NaN' every time:

```
function returnAverage(){

    var averageArray = [];
    var sum = 0;
    var sampleEnd = values.length

    for (var x = sampleEnd - 100; x < sampleEnd; x++) {
        averageArray[x] = values[x]
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < averageArray.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(averageArray[i]);
    }

    var avg = sum/averageArray.length;
    console.log(avg)

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's `values`? Is it guaranteed to be at least 100 long?

Comment: Agree with @TedHopp. If values is empty or if it contains a non-numeric character you'll end up with NaN.

Answer (score 2):

If values is a array of numbers, last maximum 100 items average:

```
function returnAverage(values) {
  var arr = values.slice(-100);

  return arr.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0) / (arr.length || 1);
}
```

Comment: This works well for arrays containing numerical values. OP's problem, however, may be that `parseInt(averageArray[i])` may be returning `NaN` for one or more values.

Answer (score 0):

Issue number one is that the final value of sum and averageArray.lnegth is 0.
It seems this would happen because the "value" array is empty.

See example below:

```
var values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var averageArray = [];
var sum = 0;
var sampleEnd = values.length

for (var x = sampleEnd - 7; x < sampleEnd; x++) {
    averageArray[x] = values[x]
}

for(var i = 0; i < averageArray.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(averageArray[i]);
}

var avg = sum/averageArray.length;
console.log(avg)
```

Edit: NaN is a result of  division by zero. So you might want to check for that before calculating:

```
if(sum == 0 || averageArray.length == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```